# Loop through Interfaces of an object

Tags: c#, generics, design-patterns, reflection

I'm creating a generic Service Locator, but have a problem.
I have a method to add or replace a service. The service has to be replaced if there is only 1 candidate in the current service list.

```
// IA  - TestA
// IB  - TestB
// IA/IB - TestAB
// <IB> TestAB 
public static void AddOrReplaceService<T>(T serviceToAdd) where T:  class
{
    if (serviceToAdd == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(serviceToAdd));
    List<T> foundServices = new List<T>();
    int index = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < _services.Count; i++)
    {
        if (!(_services[i] is T) 
            && !_services[i].GetType().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T))
            && !_services[i].GetType().IsInstanceOfType(serviceToAdd)
            && !serviceToAdd.GetType().IsInstanceOfType(_services[i]))
            continue;
        foundServices.Add((T) _services[i]);
        if (index == -1)
            index = i;
    }
    switch (foundServices.Count)
    {
        case 0:
            AddService(serviceToAdd);
            break;
        case 1:
            _services[index] = serviceToAdd;
            return;
        default:
            throw new MultipleServicesAlreadyExistsException("Multiple services found with " + typeof(T).Name
                                                + foundServices.ToStringCollection(", "));
    }
}
```

To test my Service Locator I have 2 interfaces `IA` and `IB` and 3 classes, `TestA : IA`, `TestB : IB` and `TestAB : IA, IB`

The thing is if both `TestA` and `TestB` are in the list and you try to add `TestAB` it should give an exception because both `TestA` and `TestB` are implementing interfaces of `TestAB`.

I tried to add a bunch of `AssignableFrom` etc. logic. However, I can't get it to work.

Here is part of a unit test

```
[Test]
public void Test()
{
    try
    {
        ServiceLocator.Reset();
        Assert.IsTrue(AddService<IA>(new TestA(), false));
        Assert.IsTrue(AddService<IB>(new TestB(), false));
        // TestAB implements IA and IB so replacing should fail;
        Assert.IsTrue(AddOrReplaceService<IB>(new TestAB(), true));
```

Help would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, why do you need to use [service locator](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/) in the first place ?

Comment: How AddOrReplaceService() has been called? Could you, please, provide a code?

Comment: The signature of `AddOrReplaceService` used in the unit test does not seem to match the method you have provided. It does not have a `bool` return type and also does not accept a second parameter of type `bool`.

Comment: ye my bad @OlivierJacot-Descombes. I made an UnitTest method with the same name that calls it, but has a boolean if it expects an exception

Answer (score 0):

Well, your logic is flawed. Here is what's happening:

1. 2 first calls in UT to AddOrReplaceService() adds 2 services to the service collection
2. 3rd call in UT would replace TestB class with copy of TestAB, because TestA is not assignable from IB

There never would be a situation, when count of `foundServices` would be more, then 1.
So, in order to see exception being thrown you would need to remove 2nd condition from the switch inside `AddOrReplaceService()`. And you should not check for implementation of any interfaces, other than one you are trying to add to your collection.

Answer (score 0):

Using a dictionary having the interface type as key would be much easier and more performing as no looping would be required.

```
private static readonly Dictionary<Type, object> _services = new Dictionary<Type, object>();

public static void AddOrReplaceService<T>(T serviceToAdd) where T:  class
{
    if (serviceToAdd == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(serviceToAdd));
    _services[typeof(T)] = serviceToAdd;
}
```

This automatically does several things:

1. It ensures that only one service is registered per interface.
2. It automatically adds a service if the interface has not already been registered.
3. It automatically replaces existing services for the same interface.

Since you typed the parameter `serviceToAdd` as `T`, the C# compiler ensures that the service class is assignment compatible to the interface `T` (no need to test). Also, there is no need to test whether the service you are going to replace is of the right type, as it was added by this same method that can only be called with a service of the right type.

See: [Dictionary.Item[TKey] Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.item?view=netframework-4.7.2)